# Link button doesn't function in javascript

Tags: javascript, url, button, onclick

I have this button in javascript .

```html
 <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = " ' + urlOfNewTask + ' "; return false;">{{"view_task"|translate}}</a>\
```

All I want to do is to close this modal after I click on it( for this I insert return false) and this button to take me to the link inside the onclick function.
The problem is that when I click at the button nothing happens, nor close of the modal nor open the link.
Have i done something wrong?
Here is the variable :

```html
var urlOfNewTask = mytaskbaseurl + "." + data.taskEscUrl;
```

Comment: try without the funky quotes!! `"window.location.href = urlOfNewTask; return false;"` or `"window.location.href = 'urlOfNewTask'; return false;"` if `urlOfNewTask` is a string literal and not some variable

Comment: here's a tip to writing inline javascript .... write it ... then add quotes around it - if you use single quotes in the script, use double quotes around it, and vice versa ... if you (have to) use both `'` and `"` **in** the script - then escape the ones you surround the script inside the script

Comment: No url is  a variable

Comment: then use the first form I said

Comment: I editred the question

Comment: Does the answer below and my very first comment help at all?

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser developer tools console?

Answer (score 1):

Change onclick to  `onclick="window.location.href = 'urlOfNewTask'; return false;"`

If `urlOfNeTask` is variable then try :

```
onclick="window.location.href = urlOfNewTask; return false;"
```

Comment: assuming `urlOfNewTask` is the literal string `urlOfNewTask`, rather than some global variable (which seems to be the case)

Comment: Yes. @JaromandaX  you are right. So I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: If url is variable and declared global then you can use second answer

Comment: Can you add your html and javascript code it will help me solve your problem faster

Comment: You can declare var urlOfNewTask globally so it can be accessed by onclick part.